# Django - Detect unique users. Ignore/Ban Fraud Users

Tags: django

I've a web portal where user comes in and post his/her images. Now there's a contest running where people can pool in their photos and whoever has maximum likes on its image wins the contest.

So, the problem that I'm facing is one user can register as many accounts as he/she wants and like his/her own image. This will increase the number of likes on the image and the user will win, not legally but its a fraud.

So, is there any way in which I can restrict a only 1 signup from one computer. OR is there any other better way of handling this, even if I can minimize this behaviour it will be of good help.

One method I thought of is I can ask for user's phone number and can verify using an OTP. What cab be other ways of finding the fraud accounts?

Is there any way in which I can get the unique identity of the system(probably MAC address) in Django request variable via which I can allow only 1 user registration per system?

Comment: You could only use multiple resources together to increase the uniqueness of the user, like email + phone + address combined. `IP` is no good because there are tons of tools to manipulate the IP of a computer. What if two different user tried to use one computer to register?

Comment: Good point @vmonteco but 100 people sitting in an office with 1 wifi connection will share the same public IP. I dont want to loose on those 100 different people.

Comment: @ShangWang - Thanks for the suggestion, but address can be spoofed too. Plus an email as well. A user can create another email address and can verify him/herself as the authorized user. But I can verify using an OTP on mobile.

Comment: Can i get the unique identity of the system the user is signing up from?

Comment: Email cannot be spoofed, you need to send a confirmation in the email and they have to open the email and accept the confirmation. There's no ultimate solution as everything is possible, it's just a way to minimize it.

Comment: @ShangWang: "Email cannot be spoofed,"  Well, it sort of can. If you have your own domain(s), like I do, then it is trivial to create an infinite number of sock puppet emails. IP is somewhat more difficult to diddle with (but not *that* much). The question is: is doing any of this *worth it?*

Answer (score 0):

There's no foolproof way, but you can make it harder for fake users with the following steps:

1. Show a [captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) to prevent automated sign-ups.
2. Track IP address when users sign-up and try to find patterns e.g. too many sign-ups from a single IP could signal fraud. It's also possible that the IP belongs to an organization and the users are genuine.
3. Check for suspicious IP addresses (e.g. those through VPN or cloud service providers e.g. AWS). You'll have to use a service that identifies VPN specific IP addresses. Also see : https://security.stackexchange.com/a/85416
4. If you want to get more technical, you could look at the highest liked photos and see if the users who liked it also liked other pictures. Look for tell tale signs. This could give you a pattern to distinguish fake & genuine likes.
5. [Browser fingerprint](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)

P.S. Phone number verification is also a good option since getting a disposable phone number usually isn't free. There are a few disposable free numbers that you could blacklist (search for `free disposable phone number`).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to focus your effort on the problem. The problem that you want to solve is that people can like their own images to artificially increase their own score.

To be most effective, target the problem (multiple likes) instead of the side-issue (multiple registrations).

Here are some simple suggestions:

- Prevent multiple likes from a single IP on a single image
- Set a cookie when a like is given; if the cookie is set, do not accept more likes
- Add a CAPTCHA. (This won't prevent multiple manual submissions, but will limit automated ones.)

There is nothing wrong with limiting registrations, but be sure to take steps first that address the core problem.